# Oracle script returning different number of records on adding extra column in select clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a issue with my script execution. below script returns me 744 records on my database, but if I  re-write this same script adding "cnt" column is select list, this script returns 740 records, tried a lot, but couldn't find a reason of reducing result rowcount on adding a extra column in "SELECT clause".

```
Select NVL(E.Employee_Ident, '-') EmpId,
   Z.EmpLastName || ', ' || z.EmpFirstname EmpName,
   z.DOB,
   z.EmpPersonId,
   z.DepPersonId,
   NVL(z.PlanType, 131999) PlanType,
   z.Empstat,
   z.Status  from (Select ML.personid EmpPersonId,
           EL.personid elpersonid,
           EL.plantype elplantype,
           Ml.plantype mlplantype,
           ML.name_last EmpLastName,
           ML.name_first EmpFirstName,
           EL.DepId DepPersonId,
           EL.name_last DepLastName,
           EL.name_first DepFirstName,
           ML.plantype PlanType,
           ML.EmpStat,
           NVL(EL.status, 2) Status,
           NVL(to_char(EL.Birthdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy'), '-') DOB,
           sum(case
                 when status = 0 or status = 1 or EmpStat = 1 or EmpStat = 2 then
                  1
                 else
                  0
               end) over(partition by DepId) Cnt
      from (select DCES.*,
                   cfm.employee_personid PersonId,
                   Dep.Name_Last,
                   Dep.Name_First,
                   Dep.Personid          DepId,
                   Dep.Birthdate
              from (select ChildId,
                           v2.plantype PlanType,
                           nvl(v1.status, v2.status) status
                      from (select d.family_member_personid ChildId,
                                   d.plantype               PlanType,
                                   d.status                 status
                              from cb_enrollment_status d
                             where d.employee_personid <>
                                   d.family_member_personid
                               and d.enrollment_type <> 120008
                               and d.plantype in (131001, 131002)) v1 partition by(v1.ChildId)
                     right outer join (select 131001 plantype, 2 status
                                        from dual
                                      union all
                                      select 131002 plantype, 2 status
                                        from dual) v2
                        on (v1.plantype = v2.plantype)) DCES,
                   cb_person dep,
                   cb_family_member cfm
             where cfm.family_member_personid = DCES.ChildId(+)
               and cfm.delete_status = 0
               and cfm.special_enrollee <> 1
               and cfm.family_member_personid = Dep.personid) EL,
           (select p.personid,
                   p.name_last,
                   p.name_first,
                   v2.plantype PlanType,
                   nvl(v1.status, v2.status) Empstat
              from cb_person p,
                   (select s.employee_personid PersonId,
                           s.plantype          PlanType,
                           s.status            status
                      from cb_enrollment_status s
                     where s.employee_personid = s.family_member_personid
                       and s.enrollment_type <> 120008
                       and s.employee_personid in
                           (select distinct employee_personid
                              from cb_family_member
                             where delete_status = 0
                               and special_enrollee <> 1)
                       and s.status in (0, 1)
                       and s.plantype in (131001, 131002)) v1 partition by(v1.personid)
             right outer join (select 131001 plantype, 2 status
                                from dual
                              union all
                              select 131002 plantype, 2 status from dual) v2
                on (v1.plantype = v2.plantype)
             where p.personid = v1.personid) ML
     where ML.Personid = EL.Personid(+)
       and ML.PlanType = NVL(EL.PlanType, ML.PlanType)) Z,
   (select distinct *
      from (select e.Employee_Ident,
                   personid,
                   change_sequence,
                   max(change_sequence) over(partition by personid) r
              from cb_employee e
             where coalesce(E.Hiredate_Rehire,
                            E.Hiredate_Original,
                            to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                                    'MM/DD/YYYY')) <=
                   to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
     where change_sequence = r) E where e.personid = z.emppersonid  order by lower(z.EmpLastName),
      lower(z.EmpFirstName),
      z.EmpPersonId,
      lower(z.DepLastName),
      lower(z.DepFirstName),
      z.DepPersonId,
      z.PlanType
```

above script returns 744 records.

if I change select list  to

```
Select NVL(E.Employee_Ident, '-') EmpId,
   Z.EmpLastName || ', ' || z.EmpFirstname EmpName,
   z.DOB,
   z.EmpPersonId,
   z.DepPersonId,
   NVL(z.PlanType, 131999) PlanType,
   z.Empstat,
   z.Status, Z.cnt
```

it returns 740 records.

Need to know what are possible reasons for this

Comment: Please give the DDL for your tables and a minimum working sample of data (preferably as insert statements) that shows the issue ([SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) is a good resource for creating a minimal working example in).

Comment: What is the count(*) without selecting any column? Also give your second complete query too. There should be some difference. Because the select clause runs at last. Before that all the joins/where/group/order by finishes. So changing just the select query shouldn't change your result ideally. I would be really surprised if it does.

Comment: Try to run both queries using +RULE hint. There were several bugs in Oracle where different exec plan caused wrong query results. BTW what is the db version? Isn't it 11gR1 ?

Comment: @ibre5041: Yes DB version is 11gR1.

Comment: @Utsav: I am equally surprised, because cnt column was not in initial select list, but was being used in where clause like [ nvl(cnt,0)<>2  ], and to see what values cnt has, I added cnt in select, and surprisingly result count got changed then I tested it many times by just adding and removing cnt from select and result was getting changed.

Comment: @ibre5041: Thansk a lot, +RULE hint worked and now results are same in both cases. I am now learning about it. Thanks again!!

Comment: Sorry  @ibre5041: this credit is yours.

Comment: Exact DB version : Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: If there are functional indexes on table, try to drop them. Anyway you should open a SR with Oracle and ask them for assistance. Or at least upgrade to 11.2.0.4.

Comment: For example this hint is a workaround for one of several "wrong result" bug in Oracle 11g. /*+ opt_param('_replace_virtual_columns','false') */